# SQL Server XML query() - Missing parent node or namespace

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

We need to query concatenated tags from XML records stored in a SQL Server database by querying sub sections of XML documents. The only tricky issue is that some of our records are missing the parent node, other don't. The other aspect is that that some records contain namespaces in the root and other don't.

So two things here, how can we adjust the path in the `query()` to ignore namespaces and query all mynode sections regardless of the namespaces. And how to query all the mynode sections regardless of the presence of the root node.

```
select 
    xmlCol.query('*:rootnode/*:mynode/*') 
from 
    DataTable
```

Any help on this would be appreciated

Thanks

Have a good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use double slash (//) to find a node , independently in which parent node is belonging to..

So i suppose that it should be something like

```
select xmlCol.query('//mynode/*') from DataTable
```

but more information about your table would be helpful.

Hope that helps!